# Populate data to UIcollectionview cell created with xib

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have create my custom collectionview cell with its own class. And I will register them programmatically on a UIviewcontroller class. 
The problem I facing now is, I will do all the API call on the UIviewcontroller class but how to I populate them on all the cells I want, because each cell class also will have their own data source and delegate extension.

Note: There is a one cell class inside contain another collectionview.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that each cell, also has a collectionview

Comment: @VIP-DEV  just one cell will have collectionview inside, others are normal cells. could you guide me on how to populate data into such case?

Comment: Since only one cell is going to have the mentioned case of cell containing collection view, we need to make that cell static i.e pre-define it.

Comment: @VIP-DEV can we chat on some chatting platform? as I am quite urgent now, sorry for request you this way

Comment: Join this room for discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/170469/ioscollectionview